# Insight into Service Status, availability and performance

Tags: integration, monitoring

Even if a PaaS solution abstracts the operational side of services for the consumer, me as the responsible guy in the enterprise for the application i need to have insight into the end-to-end view of the application. So in BM speak, into the runtime as well as into the service.
Is there any way to funnel back information from the BM (either through monitoring services in BM) to my entperise event management system?

I am asking here for funneling back information from runtimes as well as getting at least some status information from the services.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't speak BM (insert joke here) or know what BM means.

There are Application Performance Monitoring (APM) tools which plug into PaaS solutions which provide the end to end view and performance of applications hosted on that kind of abstraction. Most of them will bridge apps and transactions which span both the PaaS components and non-PaaS components.

I have a background in monitoring these types of apps when I was an end user, I was also the expert at Gartner on this space for 4 years, and I've recently moved to a vendor who builds these tools. The company I work for (AppDynamics) does exactly this and we have a ton of PaaS integrations and capabilities (and customers). Feel free to reach out to me and/or the company if you have questions.

We also do have competitors, but you'll find we are the only solution which is both PaaS friendly and provides a full end to end transaction path visibility for every transaction. The challenges with PaaS systems is that they are highly dynamic and the PaaS itself handles scale up and scale down, we are designed for these specific use cases.